# Cannot wake up MacBook Pro display using the "Wake on LAN" feature

Tags: display, sleep-wake, remote-control, wake-on-lan

I am trying to use the "Wake on LAN" feature to remotely turn on the display of my MacBook Pro running Catalina. **I have confirmed that "WoL" feature is working properly and the MBP awakes** into some state, however the display never turns on. Neither the laptop display nor the HDMI connected display light up.

I have tried several things already:

- Changing macOS config to `darkwake=0`, i.e. https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/342002-darkwake-on-macos-catalina-boot-args-darkwake8-darkwake10-are-obsolete/. The change of this setting didn't do anything
- Using `sleepwatcher` https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sleepwatcher. The sleepwatcher script only runs when I physically push a button on the computer.

Any ideas what else I can try to make this work?

**UPDATE**: Seems like the only way to wake the display up is using SSH commands sent to the Mac, see detailed answer below.

Comment: you checked the [„Wake for network access" -option](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1168/mac) is selected in System Preferences > Energy Saver?

Comment: @slartibartfast The OP has already said that it does wake. The issue is getting the screen to turn on at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this forum and my personal experience:

- https://www.tweaking4all.com/forum/macos-x-software/waking-up-a-mac-with-wake-on-lan/

> WOL does indeed wake up the Mac, but only in a, what may be called, "dark wake" state. In this dark wake state the monitor remains off and applications actually do not "run".

Macos WOL will wake up the system from a sleep, but the display will be off & locked. So processes can start running in the background, but not many apps, but the display is not visible. I created a script that you can run via SSH after doing WOL that wakes up the display with applescript.

Comment if you want the script i use

**Edit: here's the shell script I use to wake up my mac's display**

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

# how many seconds into the future we want to wake the display
# 2 seems to be the minimum for my network and it works reliably

# to calculate the time, we need `date`
alias set_wake_time='/bin/date -v+2S "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"'

# this is where we set the wake command
# if it doesn't succeed the script will exit immediately
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pmset schedule wake "`set_wake_time`" || exit 1
```

Comment: doesn’t this depend on wether the system is sent into standby versus autopower off? can the OP kindly post their current settings using _pmset -g_ in the terminal?

Comment: @slartibartfast the OP states that “the MBP wakes up in some state,” so that isnt the issue. The issue is how apple has implemented WoL: to not wake up the display

Comment: I understood the MBP of the OP can WOL. I thought that the preference setting might have an impact on the display state and might not be active because the power saving mode was set via terminal. AFAIK Apple implemented 3 ways of machine “sleep”: standard sleep, safe sleep and hibernate mode  - it might be worth to check with pmset wether there is a difference. (Anectdotically there is a huge difference for different MBP models to have them really sleep or hibernate - and this seems like a “reverse problem” of that.) BTW. which MBP model is it?

Comment: a remote login via SSH as suggested by @anonymous above and executing from the command line something like _osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using command down'_ might do the trick (? my MB is currently in repair so I can not check). AFAIK Macs wake up automatically upon incoming ssh connection, no Wake-on-LAN required.

Comment: I have added my script to the answer. I use pmset. Much more reliable than keystroke

Comment: OP here, it seems like `ssh` commands is the only way to achieve this. This doesn't help me exactly because I wanted to use a Kodi remote Android app to turn on my Mac's screen (The app has a "WOL" wake feature) and use the Kodi media center app. I guess I could use an SSH app on Android and run scripts that way, but then I need more apps... Anyway, thank you for the answers and discussion on this!

Comment: You could also look into tasker.

Comment: maybe the OP should set up a new thread - because I think it’s clear that the original question is answered - but I do not fully understand what he wants to achieve according to their last comment?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I’ve been search this particular issue on my 2018 MacBook Pro. I had a hunch what the issue was and was correct. The WOL is working but on macbooks it doesn’t wake up the screen! I have no idea why. I found ONE app on the AppStore that wakes mine:

OFF

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/off-shutdown-and-wake-on-lan/id529923825

It scanned my system and reported port 1984 as the upnp mapped wake on lan port. I forwarded 1984 external/1984 internal to my MacBook internal ip. And it wakes the display as well, why it goes and others don’t, hit me. It does run a helper app on the MacBook to enable other functions but I have a hunch it might be running a wol packet sniffer then launching a script to wake the display as well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).